# Label based on Day of the Week

Tags: objective-c, string-comparison

I am trying to display Happy Hour specials for bars according to the day of the week it is but for some reason the label is not matching with the current date. I am fairly new to Xcode so I am not sure if I am overlooking something.. Here is my code:

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEEE"];
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:today];
    NSLog(@"date: %@", dateString);
    lblTitle.text = pawpost.title;
    lblPhone.text = pawpost.phone;
    if ((dateString = @"Thursday")) {
        happy.text = pawpost.thu;
    }
    else if ((dateString = @"Monday")) {
        happy.text = pawpost.mon;
    }
    else if ((dateString = @"Tuesday")) {
        happy.text = pawpost.tue;
    }
    else if ((dateString = @"Wednseday")) {
        happy.text = pawpost.wed;
    }
    else if ((dateString = @"Friday")) {
        happy.text = pawpost.fri;
    }
    else if ((dateString = @"Saturday")) {
        happy.text = pawpost.sat;
    }
    else if ((dateString = @"Sunday")) {
        happy.text = pawpost.sun;
    }
```

Comment: Hint: the assignment operator is not the way to compare two objects to see of the have the same value.

Comment: Note that `dateString` may not be `Monday` or any other of the constants you listed if the user has his locale set to something non-english.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use the `isEqualToString:` method:

```
if([dateString isEqualToString:@"Monday"]) {
    happy.text = pawpost.mon;
}
```

You might also want to localize that `@"Monday"` string literal.